# Access object property using variable in dust.js

Tags: javascript, dust.js

```
{#access_map.modifiable_objects}
    <div class='col-md-2 col-xs-4'> 
        <i class="fa {icon}"> </i>
        <span> {name} </span>
        {#mods}
            {>"dust/admin/helpers/form-checkbox" name="{form_name}" label="{display_name}" value="{value}"/}
            <p> {data.powers.{id}} </p>
        {/mods}
    </div>
{/access_map.modifiable_objects}
```

I have the following code above.

Notice how `{data.powers.{id}}` is used. My real intention is to do something like : `data.powers[<id_name_here>]` or `data.powers.<id_name_here>;`

However, it renders a string. The scope of ID however, **SURELY** reaches that part where I used it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I got the answer.

It's supposed to be {data.powers[id]} and not data.powers[{id}]; It works.

Answer (score 1):

Dust doesn't currently support variable substitution natively. You could write a small helper to do what you want instead.

```
dust.helpers.get = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var key = context.get(context.resolve(params.key));
  return chunk.reference(key, context);
};
```

Then you can use the helper like this:

```
{@get key="data.powers.{id}" /}
```

If `id` were `foo`, this would output the value of `data.powers.foo`.